# Mysql : Is adding column take same time as renaming column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with around 70 million records. Here if I want to add new columns to the table it is quite heavy operation in terms of time and space.

In order to resolve this problem I thought of adding some extra columns like column1 to column10.

Now what I have to do is just rename the column.

But is renaming column going to cost me same as adding new column ?

Comment: What did you mean _'In order to resolve this problem'_ ? I.e. why not to add columns with proper names in one step? So no matter how much costs renaming - you'll get rid of it

Comment: Have you ever heard about DB Design?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2086940/174184

Comment: Disagree with close votes. It's not off topic, and although similar to the 'duplicate' question is not enough to warrant a duplicate vote. Someone searching for the above question will not yield the 'duplicate' cited in the close vote. I think this falls into 'subtle differences that may make them legitimately standalone questions' as per http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/

Comment: @AlmaDo, We don't know what columns we need to add, here we are parsing some logs to do analytics, we never know what information from logs may be required. Although this is temporary solution, but then also we are facing this problem. Hope you understood it. Also my main concern here is not db design, I just want to know whether adding a new column and renaming a new column are of same complexity or not.